# android zxing library for qr code

Tags: android, zxing

When i scan this barcode

[image]

i get this resultScan

[image]

but i want this content result to detect if it contains SMS or Email Message in that way, for example if this content contains EMail Message i need to open Email window and i want to fill fields such as To: with this email, also subject and Body.

my code up to now is:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    IntentResult scanResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    String content = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
}
```

Comment: you can break your content string on basis of semi colon to get your separate messages

Comment: separate the bundle values and if you find email in it then email else SMS

Comment: Vivek MIshra what if I have semicolon in Body

Comment: Is there any method in zxing that automatically detect what kind of type is scanResult, and how to get email, subject and body that is returned from qrBarcode

Comment: My question is how to get the type of the barcode like Text, URL, Address book, Phone Number, Email address.

Answer (score 2):

You need to double check if email TO have more then one, in this example i considered just one e-mail. If you see email.getTos() method, you'll see that is a String[].

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    IntentResult scanResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

    Result res = new Result(scanResult.getContents(), null, null, BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE);
    ParsedResult parserdResult = ResultParser.parseResult(res);

    Log.d("GORIO", "TYPE: " + parserdResult.getType().toString());

    switch (parserdResult.getType()) {
        case ADDRESSBOOK:
            Log.d("GORIO", "ADDRESSBOOK: " + parserdResult.getDisplayResult());
            break;
        case EMAIL_ADDRESS:
            Log.d("GORIO", "EMAIL_ADDRESS: " + parserdResult.getDisplayResult());
            EmailAddressParsedResult email = (EmailAddressParsedResult) parserdResult;

            if (email.getTos().length > 0)
                Log.d("GORIO", "E-mail: " + email.getTos()[0] + " Subject: " + email.getSubject() + " Body: " + email.getBody());
            break;
        case PRODUCT:
            ProductParsedResult prod = (ProductParsedResult) parserdResult;
            Log.d("GORIO", "PRODUCT: " + scanResult.getContents());
            break;
        case URI:
            URIParsedResult uri = (URIParsedResult) parserdResult;
            Log.d("GORIO", "URI: " + scanResult.getContents());
            break;
        case GEO:
            GeoParsedResult geo = (GeoParsedResult) parserdResult;
            Log.d("GORIO", "GEO: " + scanResult.getContents());
            break;
        case TEL:
            TelParsedResult tel = (TelParsedResult) parserdResult;
            Log.d("GORIO", "TEL: " + scanResult.getContents());
            break;
        case SMS:
            Log.d("GORIO", "SMS: " + scanResult.getContents());
            SMSParsedResult sms = (SMSParsedResult) parserdResult;
            Log.d("GORIO", "SMS: " + sms.getNumbers());
            break;
        case CALENDAR:
            Log.d("GORIO", "CALENDAR: " + scanResult.getContents());
            break;
        case ISBN:
            ISBNParsedResult isbn = (ISBNParsedResult) parserdResult;
            Log.d("GORIO", "ISBN: " + scanResult.getContents());
            break;
        default:
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank u so much @Gorio, it was helpful for me

Answer (score -1):

I scan your qrcode and get these raw text: "MATMSG:TO:gresa@gmail.com;SUB:hello;BODY:hdfukfhdksu;;".

Step 1.You should parse your schema get a EmailSendObject such as below:

```
   public static EmailSendObject parseQrcodeText(String rawText){
        //todo parse;
        EmailSendObject.recipent;//should be "gresa@gmail.com"
        EmailSendObject.subject;//should be "hello"
        EmailSendObject.cc;
        EmailSendObject.content;//should be "hdfukfhdksu;"
        return EmailSendObject;
    }
```

Step 2.Send Email by android action : "ACTION_SENDTO".

```
 public static void sendEmail(Activity activity,EmailSendObject object){
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("mailto:"+object.recipient);
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, uri);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_CC, object.cc);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, object.subject);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, object.content);
    activity.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Choose a email app!"));
}
```

Comment: Read the question and comments again: **My question is how to get the type of the barcode like Text, URL, Address book, Phone Number, Email address.** It's nothing related to email intents.

Comment: EmailSendObject don't recognize, should i create a class

Comment: Identifying these kinds of result(Text, URL, Address book, Phone Number, Email address), it depends on the schema.No way automatically detecting!You should parse it one by one.My answer is how to parse Email text and send Email.

Comment: Yes ,you should create this class:EmailSendObject. @Ges